# jQuery validation quirk - blocking submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My submit button is being blocked if my required field is triggered. If I fill it in, I have to click outside the input to validate the field again, thusly having to press submit twice.

Any ideas if it's by submit handler causing this?

```
// FORM
// validate enquiry form
var product_form = jQuery('#product_enquiry_form');
jQuery(product_form).validate({ 
    onkeyup: true, 
    submitHandler: product_enquiry_submit,
    errorElement: 'div',
    wrapper: false,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element); // default function
    }
});
// submit enquiry
function product_enquiry_submit(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: jQuery(product_form).attr( 'action' ) + '?ajax=true',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: jQuery(product_form).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if (data == 'SUCCESS') {
                 jQuery(product_form).fadeOut(400, function() { 
                    jQuery('.message-sent').slideDown(400);
                 });
            }
            else if (data == 'BADCODE') {
                // robot submitting honeypot
            }
            else {
                alert('Message not sent, please try again.');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) do you assign the validation onload? 2) does the ajax trigger when the validation passes?

Comment: Also show the relevant HTML markup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection of issues could be causing this problem.

1)  `var product_form = jQuery('#product_enquiry_form');`

Your `product_form` variable already contains `jQuery()`, so when it's referenced, you don't need to wrap it inside `jQuery()` again.  You've done this in several places.

```
jQuery(product_form).validate({ ...
```

This would be sufficient...

```
product_form.validate({ ...
```

2)  `true` is not a valid value for `onkeyup`. This option is already enabled by default so setting it to `true` could break things.  Only set it to `false` or a function. Otherwise, just leave it out.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup

3)  The `wrapper` option is supposed to be a "string" that represents an HTML element like `li`, etc., not a boolean `false`.   If you don't need to wrap the `label` elements, then leave this option out.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#wrapper

**Otherwise, your code appears to be working fine:**

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/hrT4C/**